# Java ProcessBuilder: space within quotation marks

Tags: java, ffmpeg, space, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to run FFMPEG to convert and label some of my MP3-Files.

Manually using the following in a .bat file works as expected:

```
"E:\Dokumente\workspace\MusicBot\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" 
    -i "The Glitch Mob - We Can Make The World Stop.mp4" 
    -metadata author="The Glitch Mob" 
    -metadata title="We Can Make The World Stop" 
    -ab 320k "mob.mp3"
```

Now what i am trying to achieve using java's ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pr = new ProcessBuilder(FFMPEG_PATH, 
    "-i", target.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-metadata", "title=\"We Can Make The World Stop\"", 
    "-metadata", "author=\"The Glitch Mob\"", 
    "-ab", "320k", 
    tar.getAbsolutePath());
```

results in a `[NULL @ 000000000032f680] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Can'`.
Using title and author without spaces in them works, however.

Comment: I'd just drop the double quotes. Have you tried that?

Comment: sometimes the most simple thing is the way to go. i did not try it, and it worked. do you want to post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes on the command line are there to tell the shell interpreter not to split your string into multiple parameters. This is to ensure that the application receives `title=We Can Make The World Stop` as a single argument.

Since `ProcessBuilder` handles multiple command line arguments explicitly, there's no need for escaping whitespace when calling it.