# How does the ProcessBuilder constructor parameter work?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm doing this:

```
String[] command = {ffmpegLoc+"ffmpeg.exe",
            "-i ",
            "\""+dir+params.getString(4)+".flv"+"\"",
            "-copyts",
            "-crf 18",
            "-profile:v baseline",
            "-level 3.0",
            "-pix_fmt yuv420p",
            "-preset veryslow",
            "\""+dir+params.getString(4)+".mp4"+"\""};
    try {
        getLogger().info("ffmpeg command " + command);
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        getLogger().info("Starting process");
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream stream =  process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line);
        }
        process.waitFor();
```

And I get this error from ffmpeg, which initializes correctly:

```
Unrecognized option 'i '.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

So I thought "Maybe I don't need to split out each argument into an array"

So I replaced the command with this:

```
String[] command = {ffmpegLoc+"ffmpeg.exe",
                "-i " + "\""+dir+params.getString(4)+".flv"+"\"" + " -copyts -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow "+"\""+dir+params.getString(4)+".mp4"+"\""};
```

And now I get this:

```
Unrecognized option 'i C:/Program'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

What happened to that hyphen before `i`?

What happened to those double quotes wrapping the path to the .flv file?

What is going on here?

Edit:

I dropped the escaped double-quotes, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933335/java-processbuilder-space-within-quotation-marks) answer, and now I get this:

```
Unrecognized option 'i C:/Program Files (x86)/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Streaming Engine 4.1.0/content/recorder/vid_test001.flv -copyts -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryslow C:/Program Files (x86)/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Streaming Engine 4.1.0/content/recorder/vid_test001.mp4'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

And again that hyphen in front of the `i` is missing.

Edit 2:

Let's combine them: No escaped double-quotes combined with arguments each on their own index:

```
String[] command = {ffmpegLoc+"ffmpeg.exe",
            "-i",
            dir+params.getString(4)+".flv",
            "-copyts", 
            "-crf 18",
            "-profile:v baseline",
            "-level 3.0",
            "-pix_fmt yuv420p",
            "-preset veryslow",
            dir+params.getString(4)+".mp4"};
```

ffmpeg now gives me:

```
Unrecognized option 'crf 18'.
```

So we got to where we encountered our first whitespace, then failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an array of strings, you are assuming some of the work the shell would do if you executed at the command line. So that's why the double quotes are unnecessary. But you need to split up the option name and the option value as separate strings; that's how the shell would pass them to the command. So, try this:

```
String[] command = { ffmpegLoc+"ffmpeg.exe",
                     "-i", dir+params.getString(4)+".flv",
                     "-copyts",
                     "-crf", "18",
                     "-profile:v", "baseline",
                     "-level", "3.0",
                     "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                     "-preset", "veryslow",
                     dir+params.getString(4)+".mp4"};
```